# Печать заголовков на каждой странице в Excel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

В моем проекте есть возможность выгрузить таблицу в Excel (реализовано с помощью PHPExcel). Таблица получается большой и ни как не умещается на одной странице формата А4.

На каждой странице должны быть заголовки!

Тут то и начинаются проблемы. Я не могу знать сколько строк уместится на странице (они имеют разную высоту), следовательно, я не могу знать где мне нужно прописать заголовок.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Как решить?

Comment: Так а почему нельзя использовать `getHeaderFooter()` и занести информацию в header? (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/phpexcel_library/1.7.4/manual.html#_Toc237519914)

Comment: А заголовки разве можно помещать что-то, отличное от текста? Мне же нужен полноценный заголовок для таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло вот это:

```
$sheet->getPageSetup()->setRowsToRepeatAtTopByStartAndEnd(8,8);
```

Закрепляет строку на каждой странице, идеально =)

Answer (score 0):

А если сплюнуть весь массив строк в Excel, а потом запустить макрос расстраничивания, который будет ориентироваться на атрибут RowHeight (например, у Cells(...)) и копировать в нужное место первый заголовок из начала?

Comment: Я тоже думал об этом, но хотелось бы без макросов обойтись.